Problem when installing ubuntu on MAC
I want to install Ubuntu on my Mac, but when I boot with EFIboot, I have this error:
init line 38: can't open /dev/sr0: no medium found

...and the installation program does not run.

What kind of Mac? Did you make changes to the bootloader? Which version of Ubuntu? Please edit to add more details

You've given no clues as to what ISO (release especially can give clue as to possible errors & meaning) but those errors can be covered by procedures, did you verify ISO? correct ISO for your systems architecture? and invalid write of ISO to install media (including unsuitable options for your unstated release & device)

This question is similar to: How do I fix "can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found" on USB boot?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you, my problem is resolved
